# How to run windows 3.11 on a virtual computer?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a disk from my old computer (Windows 3.11) the instalation diskettes are lost somewhere. Can I run it on Virtual PC? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: oh my god , you still have that , first check whether disk in good condition and working

Comment: sure it is, I have now copied in a folder and nicely zipped to 60MB :)

Comment: I would find the install media instead; easier to adapt to different hardware that way.

Comment: @grawity:Besides there is very litterl chance of the installation media appearing by magic, I do not want a random old computer - I want my old computer so clear install would not be much help :)

Comment: I didn't mention _physical_ install media.

Answer (score 1):

Your best hope would probably be to put the HDD from the Windows 3.1 box into the box you're running Virtual PC on, and using a program like [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/) to scan the physical disk into a vhd (Virtual Hard Disk) image file. (I believe the option is in the "Image" menu and called "Creating virtual hard disk image from physical drive..." or similar) Then you can create a VM in Virtual PC and choose the option to select an existing hard disk image, instead of creating a new one, and selecting the vhd file of your Win 3.11 HDD.

If you have problems booting the image, you could try Sun Microsystems's [VirtualBox for Windows](http://www.virtualbox.org/) although, there are some extra steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine said that he has done this using [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), which is essentially a virtual MS-DOS machine.  Google also shows that [it is possible](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=navclient&hl=en-GB&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLL_en-GBGB392AE393&q=Win3.11+on+DOSBox).

Remember that the original (ie. non-NT) line of Windows ran on top of MS-DOS.

I still have a fully working [ThinkPad 775c](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:755C) (my first laptop), for such nostalgia trips.

Answer (score 1):

Check your 60MB ZIP to make sure you didn't miss a few critical hidden files, IO.SYS and MSDOS.SYS, both in the root directory. Also, it may not be quite as simple as copying the files back, due to some esoteric stringent requirements about IO.SYS. Even before then, you have to format the blank virtual disk, which you can't do with DOS/Windows3 because you don't have the floppies. (There are workarounds, though.)

Overall, you might have better luck imaging the whole disk as suggested by AlanCF.

Once you can boot the the disk to DOS and try to start Windows, the main problem you will run into is driver support; that is, the emulated virtual hardware is different than the actual hardware in the old computer. VirtualPC is better than VirtualBox in this regard, because VPC emulates older hardware, for which Windows3 drivers are available (or even, ever created). For example, you can still [download Windows 3.11 drivers for the S3 Trio](http://www.s3graphics.com/en/drivers/legacy_software_archive.aspx) video card that VPC emulates (you're looking for w3117004.zip, near the bottom of the page).

If you're lucky, the actual video card in that old computer used an S3 Trio, and so the drivers are already in place. But the odds of that are not great. Better odds that the sound card was a SoundBlaster 16. In any case, I simply do not remember how installing replacement drivers worked -- perhaps rerunning SETUP.EXE

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see an accepted answer I would like to point out that Archive.org has a collection of old software, including [a VirtualBox image of Windows 3.11](https://archive.org/details/CE55E93BC43C767067BD371EFB97259FE20BC97FB09055AF7BCFD3BA374B1824). When I want to test something on an old version of Windows (or am just feeling nostalgic) I have found virtual machine images like this to be very handy.

Comment: The OVA image can be imported into Virtualbox. It boots to a DOS prompt, where you can type win to start Windows. However, any attempt to change system settings (e.g. to a 1024x768 display) fail with "File Copy Error MSDOS Error 31" for every file. Maybe it is expecting to have installation floppy disks available in the A: drive? It suggests running SETUP.EXE from DOS, which doesn't work because it only allows installing Windows to a new directory, not changing any setting. Maybe I've forgotten how to change the settings after all these years?